# is LWP::Simple faster than the full LWP?

Tags: perl, perl-module, lwp

I'm sometimes use the LWP::Simple Perl module, which I understand is a reduced version of the full LWP module. I use it blindly because somebody suggested i use it a while back. What is the benefit of using it over the full package, is it faster and is it easier to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LWP::Simple is not faster than LWP::UserAgent since it uses LWP::UserAgent. It's just a simpler interface.

Answer (score 0):

Questions of the "is A faster than B" sort, should always get the same answer: try it! In your environment, with the kind of data you generally use, etc. Here's a short script to get you started:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark qw/ cmpthese /;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://localhost/';

my $ua = sub {
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $res = $ua->get( $url );
    if ( $res->is_success ) {
        my $content = $res->decoded_content;
    }
};

my $simple = sub {
    my $content = get( $url );
};

cmpthese( -60, {
        'LWP::UserAgent' => $ua,
        'LWP::Simple'    => $simple,
});
```

On my system, where `http://localhost/` will return a tiny index page, `LWP::Simple` is actually slightly slower:

```
                Rate    LWP::Simple LWP::UserAgent
LWP::Simple    401/s             --            -3%
LWP::UserAgent 414/s             3%             --
```

But it's hard to tell what will haven, when the URL gives you a DVD image, e.g.

Comment: Re: "LWP::Simple is actually slightly slower". That's not demonstrated by your benchmark. Anything less than 5% should be considered noise. (I've seen variations of up to 10% due to how the code ends up layed out in memory!) You could also get different results depending on the type and length of the response (though you won't since LWP::Simple uses LWP::USerAgent).